# In Android Studio 4.0.0 Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, java-8, android-gradle-plugin

I downloaded Android Studio 4 and tried to test using Java 8's Streams and so on based on our application settings. Our Sdk version is 17. I updated build.gradle based on this [Android Studio 4 release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html?utm_source=android-studio) and [Java 8 Support for android](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support).
But I haven't access to Java 8 features as Stream, StreamSupport or Collections.stream(). 
I wonder what I am missing here. 
I have created a basic project with Android Studio template. The Project's build gradle looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the modules `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 17
    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.5'
}
```

And this is the `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: I would expect you to need a `compileSdkVersion` far higher than `17`.

Comment: Yes it works when I am adding compileSdkVersion. I will accept it as answer if you write it as answer. But it doesn't solve our problem. We are using SerialManager and SerialPort classes in Android platform 17 when I am writing compileSdkVersion 29 it downloads new platfrom and it doesn't find SerialPort and SerialManager

Comment: "I will accept it as answer if you write it as answer" -- I recommend that you answer your own question, as you know what changes you made to your Gradle setup that addressed the question. "We are using SerialManager and SerialPort classes in Android platform 17" -- are you sure that you are using an official Android SDK? Those classes have always been hidden, based on [the source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commits/master/core/java/android/hardware/SerialManager.java).

Comment: @CommonsWare You are right. We are using a modified version of android developed by a company for their own board. I hoped that maybe we can use java 8 features while devloping.

Comment: Other than perhaps by using reflection to work with those classes, I suspect that you are out of luck.